# SQLite step() returning SQLITE_ROW even when table is empty

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to fetch rows from a table in SQLite:

```
_tempPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                            (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
                            objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];

sqlite3         *pHandle;
sqlite3_stmt    *pStatementHandle;

NSLog(@"OPEN: %i ", sqlite3_open([_tempPath UTF8String], &pHandle));

const char *query = "select * from Transactions";

NSLog(@"PREP: %i", sqlite3_prepare (pHandle, query, -1, &pStatementHandle, NULL));

while(sqlite3_step(pStatementHandle) != SQLITE_DONE);
{
    NSLog(@"ROW");
}

sqlite3_finalize(pStatementHandle);

sqlite3_close(pHandle);
```

However, I am always getting exactly one empty row. Never matters whether the table is empty or full of entries.

The open() and prepare() commands are returning SQLITE_OK.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Long answer below. Short answer is you have extra semicolon at the end of your `while` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a semicolon at the end of the `while` statement, so your code does nothing during the `while` loop, and will then just treat the `NSLog("ROW");` as something it will do when the `while` loop is done. Thus, your code:

```
while (sqlite3_step(pStatementHandle) != SQLITE_DONE);
{
    NSLog(@"ROW");
}
```

is equivalent to doing:

```
while (sqlite3_step(pStatementHandle) != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    // do nothing
}

{
    NSLog(@"ROW");
}
```

---

As an aside, you really should be looking at the `sqlite3_step` return code, and if not `SQLITE_ROW` or `SQLITE_DONE`, display the error, if any. Thus your loop:

```
while (sqlite3_step(pStatementHandle) != SQLITE_DONE);
{
    NSLog(@"ROW");
}
```

should probably be:

```
int rc;
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(pStatementHandle)) == SQLITE_ROW) // note, no ";"
{
    NSLog(@"ROW");
}

if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
    NSLog(@"%s: step error: %d: %s", __FUNCTION__, rc, sqlite3_errmsg(pHandle));
```

In your original rendition, if you had an error, would never exit the `while` loop.

Comment: OMG. How could this happen to me! Thank you very much. It almost drove me crazy.

Comment: BTW I usually use the (result == SQLITE_ROW). I just tried the (check != SQLITE_DONE) out of desperation. But thanks for the detailed answer anyway. The hint with the additional (result != SQLITE_DONE) to check for errors is a good habit for sure.